# EJB Remote Invokation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, wildfly-10

I'm having troubles invoking a remote EJB: first time I have to do that and I may be missing something. I've read many tutorials on the web, ad several answers here on `SO`but I can't solve. That's what I've done so far.

My scenario is:

I've got two `EAR`s deployed under `Wildfly 10.0.0.Final`: `server-ear` and `client-ear`.

In `server-ear` I've got `server-api` and `server-ejb`, the first being a simple Java module containing my `EJB`s interfaces, the second being an `EJB` module containing the implementations.

Those would be

```
@Remote
public interface DummyApi {
    String getSomething();
}
```

and its implementation

```
@Stateless
@Remote(DummyApi.class)
public class DummyApiImpl implements DummyApi {
    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "SOMETHING";
    }
}
```

In `client-ear` I've got a simple `EJB` module (`client-ejb`) that defines a singleton `EJB` which takes a reference to the `DummyApi` interface:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class DummyClient {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyClient.class);

    private @EJB DummyApi dummyApi;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        log.debug("***** " + dummyApi.getSomething() + "******");
    }

}
```

In `client-ejb` I also have placed the `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file under `src/main/resources`

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

As for the interdependencies of those modules (I'm using Maven):

```
server-ear
  |---- server-api [compile]
  |---- server-ejb [compile]
          |-- server-api [provided]
```

and

```
client-ear
  |---- server-api [compile]
  |---- client-ejb [compile]
          |-- server-api [provided]
```

Both `EAR`s are dployed on the same local `Wildfly 10.0.0.Final` (clean installation of the server, no customizations whatsoever).When I start the server, I have no problems in `server-ear`.

`client-ear` instead fails with the following exception

```
12:05:22,592 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."client-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."client-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."client-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."client-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "client-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "client-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0052: Failed to install component DummyClient
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.server.api.DummyApi' for binding com.client.DummyClient/dummyApi
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.processBindings(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.access$000(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor$1.handle(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:215)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EJB will work only if beans are on same package(.ear in your case).

You will need a lookup, using the java:app name that appears in server log at startup. Something like this:

```
DummyApi api = (DummyApi) context.lookup("/server-ear/server-ejb/DummyApiImpl!path.to.DummyApi")
```

To create context:

```
private static Context createContextWildfly(String provider) throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");  
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
    return new InitialContext(properties);
}
```

Using this you don't need jboss-ejb-client.properties

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, I'm testing it now. Can you tell me if the dependencies hierarchy I described in my question is correct? First time I need to work with remote EJBs and, without any thorrough documentation and tutorials, I'm just trying to guess lots of things

Comment: Yes, seems your ear strutcture is correct. Just edited my answer with Context creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help!